# Releasing SQLite resources in F#

Tags: sqlite, f#, system.data.sqlite, fsi

Consider the following F# script, which creates a simple SQLite database and table, and then should delete it. However, the SQLite obejct doesn't seem to be disposed of properly and isn't releasing its lock on the file.

```ml
#r @"C:\Path\To\System.Data.SQLite.dll"

open System.Data.SQLite

let createTable() = 
    use db = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=test.sqlite")
    db.Open()
    let command = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE TestItems (ColA ColB)", db)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore
    db.Close()

createTable()

// System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '[...]\test.sqlite' 
// because it is being used by another process.
System.IO.File.Delete("test.sqlite")
```

I'm pretty poor at F#, but my understanding of `use` is that the object's resources will be disposed of when it goes out of scope, yet that appears to not be the case in this instance. I've tried calling `Dispose()` to no avail as well.

Can anyone shed light on how I can properly dispose of SQLite objects in F#?

Comment: Doesn't `SQLiteCommand` implement `IDisposable` as well? In that case you should also use the `use` binding instead of `let`.

Comment: That was the problem! Assumed it was a F# problem but was rather my ignorance of System.Data.SQLite. If you post an answer I'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Comment: @user1393477 A useful way I've found of avoiding this is to only use `new` with `use`, if you don't specify `new` for a class that implements `IDisposable` you'll get a warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SQLiteCommand` needs to be disposed as well, as it also implements `IDisposable` according to the docs: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand_members.html (via [`System.ComponentModel.Component`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Using `use` binding instead of `let` for `command` should solve the issue.